# git latest tag from local repository

Tags: git

This works on my local machine

```
git ls-remote --tags | grep -o 'refs/tags/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*' | sort -r | head -1 | grep -o '[^\/]*$
```

but not in my jenkins build server which is running from docker, it doesn't have the rights and I can't seem to fix that.

Is there an alternative for `ls-remote` which would give me exactly the same output, but then for my local git repository?

Or, is there a silver bullet solution for getting the LATEST tag from my local repo, looking from the tip of the branch and then backwards? I have been struggling with `git tag | head -1` and all kinds of alternatives but nothing gives me the latest tag searching back from the tip of the branch....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) is a native way, considering

> With `--abbrev` set to 0, the command can be used to find the closest tagname without any suffix

Comment: I think this solves my problem. I am using submodules. I think that complicates things. When my submodule is following master, all solutions seem to work fine. But when I `git submodule update --recursive` in my root branch, putting my subbranches in a detached mode, then `git describe` gives a weird result, it appends the git commit hash to the tag. But your solution with abbrev=0 seems to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compare version numbers.

If you are interested in "the tag with the highest version number in my repo" :

```
git tag --sort=v:refname | tail -1
```

if your version tags have a pattern to distinguish them from other tags :

```
git tag --sort=v:refname --list "v[0-9]*" | tail -1
```

note that the filter is a glob pattern, not a regexp :

`v[0-9]*` in the example above means : `v` followed by any char in `[0-9]` followed by anything else (`*`)

---

This will work if you have all tags locally, so run `git fetch --tags` before that to have an up to date list.

---

If you want "the tag with the highest version number *in the history of my current branch*" :

```
git tag --sort=v:refname --merged=HEAD | tail -1
```

If you want "the tag closest to my current commit" :

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0
```